# "Peek of a closed file" right after file is opened

Tags: python, io, pickle

I'm trying to load data from a pickled object into a list, but despite opening the file, I am receiving

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file.py", line 18, in <module>
    data.append(pickle.load(file))
ValueError: peek of closed file
```

I assumed that I missed something in opening the file, but I looked and what I have seemed fine to me (this is my first foray into IO with pickle)

```
# load data to list
with open('tasks.txt', 'rb') as file:
    data = []
    while True:
        try:
            data.append(pickle.load(file))
        except EOFError:
            break
        file.close()
```

Am I handling the opening wrong, or is it something else?

Comment: Why do you have a while True?

Comment: @Fredrik: You can store multiple pickles back to back; the loop keeps going until it runs out of things to unpickle.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You closed the file after the first `load`; remove the `file.close()` entirely (the `with` statement already handles that), and it should work fine.